# clicking on save refreshing pop-up magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, prototype

i am showing a form in pop-up window in magento admin panel.
but when i click on save. It sends request to controller action but url is getting red in console without any error.

this is my ajax post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var id = '<?php echo $recordId ?>';
    var url = '<?php echo $saveUrl ?>';
    function closePopup() {
        Windows.close('browser_window');
    }
    document.getElementById("addccbtn").onclick = function() {savecc()};
    function savecc() {
        var dataString = 'id='+id;
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                parameters: dataString,
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    var json = response.responseText.evalJSON(true);
                    if(json.success){
                        window.parent.closePopup();
                    }
                },
                onFailure: function(response) {
                    //location.reload();
                }
            });
        }



//]]>
</script>
```

and this is error which i am getting after clicking button

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on the (+) next to the red error. It will show you more details.

Comment: this is showing me three things Params, Post, Heades and Cookies but no error

Comment: The script prototype.js is not found as per the screen capture.